How do I convert a tflite action recognition model to a coreml model using coremltools convert?
I have a tflite model stored in a variable tflite_model. I used transfer learning to train the action recognition model MoViNet on a custom dataset, and I'd like to use this model in an Xcode project. I pretty much followed this notebook to do so https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DpzHy6qNbBJqLU7LoAqVmmUpmcKDHBDI#scrollTo=-0Exy6QJgep-
Here's the code used to create the tflite model from the tf model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

I am trying to convert this to a coreml model to use in an Xcode project. However when I try to convert this to a coreml model, while I don't get any error messages, the runtime disconnects, reconnects, and the codeblock has no output. Here is the code for the conversion:
class_names = list(files_for_class.keys())
classifier_config = ct.ClassifierConfig(class_names)

coreml_model = ct.convert(tflite_model, source="tensorflow") #, inputs=[ct.ImageType(scale=1/127, shape = input_shape)], classifier_config=classifier_config, minimum_deployment_target=ct.target.iOS15, convert_to="mlprogram" )

coreml_model.save("My.mlmodel")

What is going wrong, and how can I fix it?
Additionally, if it is not possible to go from tflite -> coreml, then I am also open with going from tf -> coreml. However, I am still struggling with this as well and could use some guidance.
Thank you for reading my post.

I suspect hat it's not possible to convert the MoViNet classifier to a coreml model. In that case, I may consider trying to use the tflite model in my Xcode project, however I am not sure how to go about this
